# inequalities using math node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, mathematics

Using math nodes I generated that pyramid like shape, but I want to impose inequalities.
The equation for the following pic is 9-8|x|-y=0 but I want to impose inequalities to the equation where 0.75<|x|<1. How do I integrate the equation  with the given inequality?

[image]

this is the current output
[image]

and this is the current node setup.

The final output has to look something like this
[image]

Comment: what is the final equation like?

Comment: 9-8|X|-y =0 where 0.75<|x|<1

Answer (score 2):

I used the Node Expressions add-on (available via https://baldingwizard.wixsite.com/blog/node-expressions) to create the nodes from the mathematical expression, using the following expression :

```
Val1 = abs(y-(9-8*abs(x))) < Threshold, Val2 = and(abs(x)>0.75, abs(x)<1), Combined =Val1 * Val2
```

This creates two sub-expressions (Val1 which returns 'true' if y is close to '9-8|x|' and Val2 which is true if 0.75 < |x| < 1.0) and a Combined output which is true if both sub-expressions are true.

This produces the following result :

[image: result and nodes]

Blend file included [image]